# go-colly returning just the scrapping from the first page

Tags: go, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a webpage with the colly framework, with the code below. The scrape it's okay, but it's just returning the scrape from the first page, meanwhile, there are three pages in this example.
The scraper is scrapping all three pages, but returning just the first one.

scraper.go:

```golang
package scraper

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
    "github.com/gocolly/colly/extensions"
)

func Scraper(prod, baseUrl string) []Product {

    // Replace blank spaces with '%20' to make the URL work
    var urlReplacer *strings.Replacer = strings.NewReplacer(" ", "%20")
    // Removes 'R$' from the price and remove blank spaces
    var priceReplacer *strings.Replacer = strings.NewReplacer("R$", "", " ", "")
    products := make([]Product, 0)
    prod = urlReplacer.Replace(prod)
    searchUrl := fmt.Sprintf("%s%s%s", baseUrl, "/pesquisa?pg=1&t=", prod)
    c := colly.NewCollector()
    s := Selector()
    c.OnHTML(s.main, func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        e.ForEach(s.container, func(_ int, h *colly.HTMLElement) {
            fullPrice := h.ChildText(s.fullPrice)
            product := Product{
                name:      h.ChildText(s.name),
                fullPrice: priceReplacer.Replace(fullPrice),
                link:      fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", baseUrl, h.ChildAttr(s.link, "href")),
            }
            products = append(products, product)
        })
    })

    c.OnRequest(func(r *colly.Request) {
        fmt.Println("Visiting", r.URL)
    })

    c.OnError(func(r *colly.Response, err error) {
        fmt.Println("Request URL:", r.Request.URL, "failed with response:", r.Request, "\nError:", err)
    })

    c.OnHTML(s.nextPage, func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        nextPage := urlReplacer.Replace(fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", baseUrl, e.Attr("href")))
        nextPageStr := e.Text
        isNextPage := nextPageStr == "Próximo"
        fmt.Println(nextPageStr)
        if isNextPage {
            c.Visit(nextPage)
        } else {
            e.Request.Abort()
        }
    })

    c.OnScraped(func(r *colly.Response) {
        fmt.Println("Finished", r.Request.URL)
        fmt.Println(products)
    })

    // Uses a random User-Agent in each request
    extensions.RandomUserAgent(c)

    c.Visit(searchUrl)

    return products
}
```

selector.go:

```golang
package scraper

type ProdSelector struct {
    main      string
    container string
    name      string
    fullPrice string
    link      string
    nextPage  string
}

// Export ProductSelector to be used like a constant, carrying the selectors of the website
func Selector() ProdSelector {
    return ProdSelector{
        main:      "ul.row",
        container: "div.inner",
        name:      "h3.name.no-medium.no-tablet",
        fullPrice: "strong.sale-price > span:nth-child(1)",
        link:      "a",
        nextPage:  "a.page-next",
    }
}
```

product.go:

```golang
package scraper

type Product struct {
    name      string
    fullPrice string
    link      string
}
```

main.go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/Antonio-Costa00/Go-Price-Monitor-Alibaba-Website/scraper"
)

func main() {

    products := scraper.Scraper("Guitar", "https://www.brasiltronic.com.br")
    fmt.Println(products)
}
```

I am not sure, but I think it's a problem related to asynchrony. May someone help me with this problem? Thank you for the attention.